# How to loop through a list of dictionaries that contain more than one key, and change different key values?

Tags: c#, python, dictionary

So I used to work in Python, and I've recently switched to C#. I've been trying to recreate one of my Python projects in C#, and I got stuck on a bit involving dictionaries. In a part of my Python code, I created some dictionaries with two keys each, and added all the dictionaries to a list:

```
slot0 = {"itemID": 0, "amount": 0}
slot1 = {"itemID": 0, "amount": 0}
slot2 = {"itemID": 0, "amount": 0}

inv = [slot0, slot1, slot2]
```

Then, later on, I looped through list of dictionaries, and was able to easily change the values of both the `itemID` key and the `amount` key:

```
 for slot in inv:
      if slot["item"] == 0:
           slot["item"] = 2
           slot["amount"] += 1
           break
```

However, in C#, it doesn't seem so easy. I successfully created the dictionaries and added them to a list:

```
Dictionary<string, int> slot0 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "itemID", 0 }, { "amount", 0 } };
Dictionary<string, int> slot1 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "itemID", 0 }, { "amount", 0 } };
Dictionary<string, int> slot2 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "itemID", 0 }, { "amount", 0 } };

List<Dictionary<string, int>> inv = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

private void Start()
{
    inv.Add(slot0);
    inv.Add(slot1);
    inv.Add(slot2);
}
```

But I'm not sure how to replicate the `for` loop from the Python code. I know that `foreach` is a thing, and that I can use it with KeyValuePairs, but I'm pretty sure you can't change multiple keys' values with it. If anyone could help, that would be great. Sorry if my question wasn't too clear; I would be more than happy to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant solution possible but it matches with what you have in Python. You'll be `foreach`-ing over the list which follows Python's `for` nicely. After that, you get the dictionary as `slot` and simply use the indexer with the key to access and alter their values.

```
// I use `var` because I believe it to be more "csharponic" ;).
foreach (var slot in inv)
{
    if (slot["itemID"] == 0) {
        slot["itemID"] = 2;
        slot["amount"] += 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

You should probably check out the [Dictionary docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn about possible issues accessing dictionaries. In my example, if the key you're using doesn't exist you'd end up with a `KeyNotFoundException`. To make the code more robust, add a key check into the `if` as suggested by @Sach; like so:

`if (slot.ContainsKey("itemID") && slot["itemID"] == 0) { ... }`

For completeness, you can also use `TryGetValue`.

```
foreach (var slot in inv)
{
    var v = 0;
    if (slot.TryGetValue("itemID", out v) && v == 0)
    {
        slot["itemID"] = 2;
        slot["amount"] += 1;
        break;
     }
}
```

The benefit, as @mjwills pointed out in a comment, will reduce the number of key lookups (for more on `out` see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out)). `Item[]`, `ContainsKey`, and `TryGetValue` "approach O(1).